# Keyboard layout isn't changed in Chromium under Debian

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, chrome

I have a problem with switching layouts in Chromium. If I switch keyboard layout it changes successfully, but I can't still type Cyrillic (or other) symbols in Chromium. I found out that actually keyboard layout is changed in Chromium, because symbols like <kbd>?</kbd>,  <kbd>and</kbd>  are on the different places (they are in placesion which they should be in the current layout), but I can't type letters from the current layout.

So for example I'm in English layout - I can type any letters etc. without any problems. Then I switch my layout to Russian (for example), after that I can't type any Cyrillic letters at all, I still can type only Latin letters.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me.

This issue is reported and confirmed http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378303

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.